# Telerik RadGrid - Opening NestedView fires NeedDataSource event

Tags: telerik

I have a RadGrid set up to use the NeedDataSource event.  I also have a Nested View set up to provide a quick-view of extended fields of the row.  Is it necessary to fire the NeedDataSource event when expanding a Nested View?  I would rather proactively load the fields in the initial load since I already have all my elements.  Is it possible to make the display of a Nested View entirely client side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have viewstate enabled you do not need to handle the NeedDataSource event when expanding a nested view. When a GridDataItem is set to expanded the DetailTableDataBind event fires and binds the data for the nested view.

I had the same issue and broke the retrieval of my data into two steps to accommodate the RadGrid.

Comment: I do have ViewState enabled.  How can I tell if the event is caused by expanding the nested view?

Comment: I found it... I tested for e.IsFromDetailTable in my event, and am only loading if it is false.  Works great!